# How to carry on a function from one HTML page to another?

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

```
function display() {
  document.querySelector(".recipeList").innerHTML = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < arrayOfRecipes.length; i++)
    +document.querySelector(".recipeList").innerHTML += "<button onclick='buttonDirect(" + i + ")'>Start Cooking</button>";
}

function buttonDirect(indexNum) {
  localStorage.setItem("indexNumber", JSON.stringify(indexNum));
  window.location.href = "/display.html";
  buttonClicked();
}

function buttonClicked() {
  JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("indexNumber"));
  console.log(indexNumber);
}
```

I am trying to get data (index number) from one function to carry on running after the HTML page has been changed.

Currently, I have a button which runs a function called `"buttonDirect(indexNum)"` I want this function to change from one page to another, hence why I used the `window.location.href = "/display.html";` code within the function. After this, the page changes so I attempt to save the index number by saving it to local storage with the `localStorage.setItem("indexNumber", JSON.stringify(indexNum));` code. Then since JavaScript reads the code from top to bottom, I tried to make it run the `buttonClicked();` function after the page has changed so that it doesn't run until the next page has loaded. That way, I can retrieve the index number on the next page using `JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("indexNumber"));` and then console log that number with  `console.log(indexNumber);`.

I quickly realised that this will not work, because the `buttonClicked()` function will run before the page actually changes, meaning that the `indexNumber` will not get logged once the page changes. What is the best way to achieve what I am trying to do?

Comment: It's not clear what you want to do.

Comment: If you are storing a simple string or integer in localStorage, you don't need the `JSON.parse()` and `JSON.stringify()` bits.

Comment: Do you want indexNumber to be printed on the first page or on the second page, first page wont have meaning, because it would have redirected to second page by that time, if you want it on second page then read it in second page javascript on page load.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like `buttonClicked()` won't get called because you would have left the page.

You can, when the page loads, get the data you want from local storage:

```
window.onload = function() {
  const indexNumber = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("indexNumber"));
  console.log(indexNumber);
}
```

(I added a variable for the result of `JSON.parse`.)

By the way, on the fourth line, I don't know if the `+` there is a typo

```
+document.querySelector...
^
```